# Mongodb connectivity at runtime in spring boot

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

Need to create mongodb connection at runtime with connection details comming in request headers, example, in REST get call, headers receive mongodb connection details, before hitting to mongodb query, create connection. these connection details can be dynamic. no deployment auto configuration. is this possible.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it Programaticaly after startup.

Here is an Example with h2 DB.

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
        dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
        dataSourceBuilder.url("jdbc:h2:mem:test");
        dataSourceBuilder.username("SA");
        dataSourceBuilder.password("");
        return dataSourceBuilder.build();
    }
}
```